# Stolen coins and hacked wallets

Tags: addresses

How do I track down the owner of an address that stole my wallet. I have the address need to follow up. My coins show up in their wallet.

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly can not.

Only if you're lucky and the thief is not very smart - he could be in the same country, and use a local exchange to get fiat currency. Then, maybe, the police could help (they have enough power to ask an exchange to reveal the account owner).

But this someone could just go to any exchange, replace stolen coins to any crypto (few times) transfer those into any other wallet - and you lose track of it forever.

Sorry to bring you bad news. I hope you didn't lose much.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Etherscan to see the account:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x7C887feBc897C5D1bc67fE80BFd5B3fc05F8440f

Then I added the said account to Tenderly.co (wallet monitor):
[image: so many accounts]

My plan is to monitor the wallet with some service, get notification of movement to an exchange and warn the exchange, but most probably everything has been emptied and moved so fast that it will be gone

Answer (score 0):

This is great tool for following stolen assets. It also supports multiple netwroks.

https://metasleuth.io/